# XCode 6 storyboards - how do I create a header for every scene?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

In XCode 6, how do I create a 'header' that will place a logo in the same position on each new scene that I create, that I can re-use across different scenes? I only want to place the header on some of my scenes but not others.

Answer (score 1):

create a BaseViewController and customize a 'header' in viewDidLoad. Every scene need a 'header' will inherit from BaseViewController, other scenes are not

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UIImageView programmatically:

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
let header = UIImageView(image: logo!)
header.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
view.addSubview(header)
```